# Efficient way to clone a generic object in Java preferably without a factory

Tags: java, generics, cloning

I find my self having to export references to keys in an underlying Java `collections` map. I don't want to give out references to the actual key objects but copies of them to ensure that nobody fiddles with the values and messes up the map. So I need to create a copy of an arbitrary generic type.

I already wrote a utility class that does this through in memory serialisation, but then noticed that `Collections.nCopies` also gives me copies of things.

So just to give some idea of what I am doing, I need to for instance access the next (higher/lower) key value given some other key value.

```
public class MapWrapper<T, K extends Comparable<K>>
    implements OtherThing<T, K>
{
    public K next (K current) {
        return ... cloned next highest key as per NavigableMap.higherKey()
    }
}
```

So the question is if it is better to copy the objects with

```
T copy = Collections.nCopies(1,item).get(0)
```

or to serialise the object and then deserialise it

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputBuffer);
outputStream.writeObject(item);
outputStream.close();

final ByteArrayInputStream inputBuffer = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
final ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputBuffer);T copy = null;
T item = null;
try {
    copy = (T)inputStream.readObject();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Logger.getLogger(SerialisationService.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, e);
}

inputStream.close();
inputBuffer.close();
outputBuffer.close();
```

A quick test with copying a `Long` shows that the `Collections.nCopies` is faster (0 ms / 8 ms). Is there some caveat to that method that I'm not able to think about at this late hour though, or can you think of an even better way of getting a copy of the keys?

Comment: actually the `nCopies` method returns just another reference pointing to the given element - from the docs: `The newly allocated data object is tiny (it contains a single reference to the data object).` I don't think that is what you are aiming for.

Comment: Indeed.  A much more maintainable approach would be an unmodifiability wrapper for your key type or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a significant difference - `Collections.nCopies` doesn't copy the object! It just returns a `List` containing `n` entries, all of which are the provided object ([check the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html#3451)!). Any changes made to anything you pick out from that list will be reflected in the original object. So this code:

```
Point original = new Point(0, 0);
Point supposedCopy = Collections.nCopies(1, original).get(0);
supposedCopy.x = 13;
System.out.println("x = " + original.x);
```

will print `13`, not `0`. Oops.

A serialization roundtrip isn't a bad idea. An alternative is using [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Cloneable.html), which unfortunately is kind of broken. `Cloneable` doesn't declare `clone()`, but it is [declared as `protected` in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), so you have to invoke it by means of reflection.

Personally, I'd prefer to use immutable objects in your situation, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The broken `Cloneable` is exactly what lead me onto these strange paths. I'd like to use immutable objects as well but couldn't think of a way of wrapping the key into anything that would actually make it immutable. I am still in the early stages of implementing this stuff, so if you have advice I'm happy to heed of them.

Comment: Is there a reason the objects have to be mutable in the first place? You can often avoid mutability unless you're using some lib like JPA. If you have complex objects you can use the [builder pattern](http://rwhansen.blogspot.se/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html) for mutability in the construction phase, but immutability when construction is finished.